# How to edit a web interface (front end)

Tags: frontend, octoprint

I want to make some changes to the [Octoprint 3d printing web interface](https://github.com/foosel/OctoPrint) in order to fit my expectations. In order to change values and observe the results, I apparently have to recompile every time even if the changes are on the front end and not in the back end. Is there a way to observe the changes to the front end without recompiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. The changes in front-end are contained in browser and are not dependent on server. Any changes to front-end code is immediately available to browser, and can be seen by a debugging tool - like [firebug in firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/), or [firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/).

You have to reload page on browser to load new changes in front-end code.